# A few questions regarding $\phi\rightarrow\bot$

Tags: logic

I am a self-studier. These are a few simple questions pertaining to First-Order Logic that I am sure would be covered in class. But MSE is my only resource.

Here $\phi$ is a sentence.

1) How do you verbalize $\phi\rightarrow\bot$

2) How is $\neg\phi$ equivalent to $\phi\rightarrow\bot$

3) In this context, does $\bot$ mean a contradiction

4) If you substitute $\bot$ for $\phi$ in $(\square\phi\rightarrow\phi)$, is that $(\square\bot\rightarrow\bot)$, or do things change around because of a negation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) if $\phi$, then FALSE.

2) $\bot$ is a propositional constant that is always FASLE. Thus, we have to use the truth table for the conditional ($\to$) to check $\phi \to \bot$.

When $\phi$ is evaluated to FALSE, we have that $\phi \to \bot$ is FALSE $\to$ FALSE, i.e. TRUE.

When $\phi$ is evaluated to TRUE, we have that $\phi \to \bot$ is TRUE $\to$ FALSE, i.e. FALSE.

Thus, $\phi \to \bot$ is the same as $\lnot \phi$.

3) $\bot$ is always FALSE; thus, it is equivalent to $p \land \lnot p$ and to every other contradictory formula.

4) Yes; $(□⊥→⊥)$ is a well formed formula, and it is equivalent to $\lnot □⊥$.

Comment: Please forgive me for taking so long to upvote and accept your kind answer. I had to step away to take care of something. With regards,